# how to get permalink structure with php

Tags: php, functions, permalinks

I need to make if statements for every permalink structure, so I need to know if there is a function that returns to me the actual selected permalink structure by the user.
To make it simple all I need to know is if this permalink:

```
www.site.com/?p=22;
```

a condition will apply else if this structure

```
www.site.com/cat/title
```

is used then another condition is applied.

So all I need to know is if there is function in Wordpress that can return me what structure the website is using.

Answer (score 8):

The structure is stored in the option `permalink_structure`. Pretty permalinks are disabled if the option is empty.

```
$structure = get_option( 'permalink_structure' );
```